# Laptop battery doesn't last that long compared to Windows

Tags: power-management, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my computer get less battery life with Ubuntu compared to Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93654/why-does-my-computer-get-less-battery-life-with-ubuntu-compared-to-windows)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome 3.6 on a Dell Inspiron N5010 laptop, but I have a problem with the power handling/battery. As soon as I disconnect my charger, the battery starts discharging from an indication of 51% and it lasts for only 1 hour. Compared two hours in Windows 7, this is a major difference.

I've installed Jupiter and I don't see any change. I'd appreciate some help on this, as I would like to keep using Ubuntu now.

Comment: do you have a dual graphics card? like nvidia optimus/ ati switchable graphics card?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a 2 hour battery life on Ubuntu and 4 on Windows, but then felt that all Linux-based OS's consume a lot of power, sorry for being weird, but practically it does seem so as a lot of my friends' Android phones have similar opinions.

Comment: -1 Please don't re-post the [exact same question repeatedly](http://askubuntu.com/q/233767/12864). I'm voting to close both as we have many duplicates ([1](http://askubuntu.com/q/23404/12864), [2](http://askubuntu.com/q/93654/12864), [3](http://askubuntu.com/q/174593/12864), [example search](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=battery+drain&submit=search)) of this exact issue.

Comment: I have ATI Radeon 5xxx with a driver " Gallium 0.4 on AMD REDWOOD "

Comment: Sorry for repeating I'm new for this site and don't know the rules yet.
I deleted the old post

Comment: did you try granola?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because your processor is running full at full speed or your graphics card is switch-able but not switching.

You can check and control your processor speed using a widget such as CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor. It fixed my problem with power consumption on Ubuntu 11.04.