# How to run Ubuntu 12.10 on a Laptop with maximum power saving?

Tags: performance, battery, cpu

I have a Toshiba L500-21T with Intel core I3 M330 2.13GHZ having 4 cores
with Amd Mobility Rdeon 4500 Graphic card, 360Gb HD and 6GB DDR3 RAM.

How can I run my lappy smoothly while giving me reasonable battery life and less heat generation. [I don't want to use a cooler.]

Comment: This may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers

Comment: Check [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop) out. Search for `System Requirements` on this page. You look good to go though!

Comment: check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93654/why-does-my-computer-get-less-battery-life-with-ubuntu-compared-to-windows

Comment: I run 12.10 as a secondary OS on my laptop, booting off of an external HDD.  My specs are much worse than yours, and i get about 4 hours of bat life by turning the backlight down.  Other than the backlight, what kind f power saving features does ubuntu have?

Answer (score 0):

try installing jupiter

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

this may work

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for;

http://www.linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html

TLP is a power management tool for Linux. It brings you the benefits of advanced power management without the need to understand every technical detail.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Never heard of this before :-D ... so is this better than jupiter?

Comment: Try before & after with PowerTOP.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681