# Battery Drains very fast

Tags: dual-boot, hp, battery

I am using hp pavillion notebok with windows and  ubuntu dual boot, whenver i shutdown my laptop and start the ubuntu after some time, i founds that the charging is reduced very much. I have tried the hp's utility for checking wethter battery is working fine or not and the utility says that it is working fine, so where it the problem

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/93654/why-does-my-computer-get-less-battery-life-with-ubuntu-compared-to-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my computer get less battery life with Ubuntu compared to Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93654/why-does-my-computer-get-less-battery-life-with-ubuntu-compared-to-windows).

Comment: I don't get it... why it is duplicated? there is no hardware details, os details provided by the user, secondly you pointed to a question that was for a bug, which was fixed later (see the comment in the answer).

Comment: Video Graphics AMD Radeon HD 7670M (1 GB DDR3 dedicated)
Display 15.6" diagonal HD BrightView LED-backlit Display (1366 x 768)

Comment: Video Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 7670M (1 GB DDR3 dedicated )
                                                          Display: 15.6" diagonal HD BrightView LED-backlit Display (1366 x 768)                                                             Power : 90W AC power adapter  6-cell Lithium-Ion (Li-Ion)                                                         These are the specifications of my laptop and the ,and the os is ubuntu Release 12.10 (quantal) 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have laptop which uses [optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html) technology. The idea behind optimus is that you have a weaker Intel based graphics card which will be used by standard applications that do not require much 3d power and an Nvidia graphics card which should be used by games, rendering software etc... Using this setup allows your laptop to benefit from increased battery life as well as good performance when required.

Unfortunately, Nvidia has not shown much support for this technology on linux and as a result your Nvidia discrete chip will be turned on at all times when you are running Ubuntu. This results in much more power being used and why your battery is draining so fast.

In order to fix this, you can install [bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) which will provide you with the power management required to give you a much longer battery life and the appropriate tools to run applications using the Nvidia chip when required.

As far as i know, the only thing bumblebee is currently missing is:
 * Automatic detection of when to run the nvidia chip (currently this has to be done manually by using the optirun or primusrun command)
 * HDMI out support if it is wired to your NVidia chip.

Of course, this is all under the assumption that you are using an HP laptop that uses optimus technology - so you will need to check yourself with a bit of googling.

EDIT: It is also possible to have hybrid technology with ATI graphics cards. I believe bumblebee still provides support for this - but i am not sure how well it does it.

Comment: No bumblebee is only for Nvidia... ATI hybrids are supported by proprietary ATI driver. Most hp laptops uses ATI

Comment: Really? The reason i mentioned that bumblebee provides support is because i frequently see message threads in the bumblebee issues section being posted - so i assumed it was require by hybrid ati laptops. Thanks for the information

Comment: My laptop is havng AMD Radeon HD 7670M (1 GB DDR3 dedicated) graphic card so what should I do.