# Poor battery life on recent Ubuntu installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, power-management, battery

I've just started using Ubuntu (or any Linux distro, for that matter). I just bought this computer ([Dell Inspiron 5593](https://www.dell.com/lt/p/inspiron-15-5593-laptop/pd)), and I've installed the latest Canonical LTS version of Ubuntu (20.04).

My battery life is, quite frankly, abysmal. I was told the battery should be lasting 7-8 hours, but it's barely lasting 3. I assumed it might be a driver issue with the NVIDIA GPU, and, as per the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1244247/1103141), I examined the "Additional Drivers" tab, where I saw that the "Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-440 (proprietary, tested)" radio button was already selected:

[image: Software & Updates screenshot]

So now I'm at a bit of a loss as to what's going on. Again, I'm new to Ubuntu and to Linux, even though I do have some rudimentary knowledge of the command line--does anyone have any recommendations of next-step diagnostics?

Comment: "I was told the battery should be lasting 7-8 hours..." told by whom? 7-8 hours under which conditions? In general the battery backup on Ubuntu is relatively lower than on Windows.

Comment: @pomsky I noticed that, but 2-3 hours seemed like a significant enough difference that I assumed there might be other factors. I'll check out the answers there, thanks. Can I trust all the answers, i.e. are they forward-compatible seeing as the question was asked 10 years ago and the top answer was edited in 2015?

Comment: `tlp` and `powertop` are the usual go-to options for many.