# Battery efficiency issue in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: power-management, battery

I have an HP Probook 440 G2, with an intel core i5-4210U processor.
I have dual boot windows 8.1 installation. I get approx 5+ hours of battery backup in Windows 8.1 and approx 2+ hours in Ubuntu. My laptop heats up too on the left side of the touchpad.
I want to know, if I can make Ubuntu better battery-wise by installing some packages.

Comment: I would recommend TLP.    See also this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter

Comment: Also this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93654/why-does-my-computer-get-less-battery-life-with-ubuntu-compared-to-windows?rq=1