# Fan noise and decresed Battary Lifetime after Ubuntu install

Tags: lenovo, battery, thinkpad, fan, hybrid-graphics

I have a fresh **Ubuntu 17.10.1** installation on my Lenovo Thinkpad e470 with the following specs:

- CPU i7 7500U with  Intel® HD Graphics 620
- GPU Nvidia Geforce 940MX
- 16GB Ram and 256GB SSD

The OS is running quite smoothly and everything is working, even the fingerprint Login.

I've only two problems with it:

1. The notebook fans are pretty loud, I think they are running at 100%. With the old OS (Windows 10) the notebook was completely silent.
2. The lifetime of the battery is short, also shorter then with Windows 10.

I think that it has something to do with the two graphics cards.

- How can I see which one is being used at the moment?
- Is there maybe a way to switch automatically between them ?

Comment: First of all you need to install the Nvidia proprietary drivers. Then, not only the CPU load should be balanced when using the Nvidia graphics, but also you'll be able to easily switch cards using the Nvidia X Server Settings profiles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my computer get less battery life with Ubuntu compared to Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93654/why-does-my-computer-get-less-battery-life-with-ubuntu-compared-to-windows)

Comment: Can you read all the sensors, and control fans, and have `fancontrol` running & set to "non-destructive" numbers?

Comment: how can i chek it Xen2050 ? i there any programm or somting else to chek the fancontrol and temperatures in ubuntu ?