# I had trouble with charging netbook Lenovo x140e

Tags: battery

I bought an old netbook. Windows 8 was installed on the netbook.
The battery charge was a maximum of 39%. Working time was 1.5-2 hours.
I reinstalled xubuntu 18.04 and it was 17%. Working time 20 minutes.
I did a complete discharge of the netbook in the bios and charged for about 3 hours.
I did this cycle several times and only increased to 24%.
The running time was 30 minutes.
I unplugged the power and the netbook was dead in 15 minutes.
After recharging and the charge became 9% and works for 5-7 minutes.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you need a new battery. These things deteriorate differently based on age, usage patterns, and temperature exposure 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my computer get less battery life with Ubuntu compared to Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93654/why-does-my-computer-get-less-battery-life-with-ubuntu-compared-to-windows)

Answer (score 1):

The battery seems to be old and/or broken. Get a new one ...